# How to remove rows from a table that doesn't fit some criteria

Tags: mysql, duplicates, delete-row

I am stuck with a problem where I couldn't find an answer so far.

I have a table like this:

```
column1 | column2 | column3
---------------------------
name1   | 3       | 12
name1   | 3       | 10
name1   | 2       | 17
name2   | 3       | 15
name2   | 3       | 15
name2   | 2       | 11
```

How can I delete the rows, which have not the highest values in `column2` and column3,(`Column2` has priority)?

The result should look like:

```
column1 | column2 | column3
---------------------------
name1   | 3       | 12
name2   | 3       | 15
name2   | 3       | 15
```

Comment: What have you tried? I suggest you split your complex problem in several simpler problems.

Comment: I can separate the problem by deleting duplicates later on using ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE KEY idx1(column1, column2, column3) - now i update my 1st post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
WHERE
  (column1, column2, column3) NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT yourtable.column1, yourtable.column2, max(column3) max_column3
      FROM
        yourtable INNER JOIN (
          SELECT   column1, max(column2) max_column2
          FROM     yourtable
          GROUP BY column1) mx
        ON yourtable.column1=mx.column1
           AND yourtable.column2=mx.max_column2
      GROUP BY
        yourtable.column1) s
  )
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c92dc9/1).

Comment: This one works exactly. However, i'm not sure if i have asked the right question. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Deleting makes it confusing but these are the rows you want to keep:

```
SELECT 
    a.col1, a.col2, b.col3 
FROM
    (select col1, max(col2) as col2 from table1 group by col1) as a INNER JOIN
    (select col1, col2, max(col3) as col3 from table1 group by col1, col2) as b 
    ON 
        a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2;
```

You could simply delete the rows that are not in this query as noted by @fthiella.

see this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a9a6/1/0).

Comment: i didn't try it out yet, because the answer above from fthiella works fine. I'll try it later, when i have more time to play around with alternatives. Thanks a lot